# How to separate old Close[1] and new Close[1]?

Tags: mql4

Task :
"If found a bullish candle, then wait until next candle close above the highest price among recent 50 candles".

I acheive the above task by writting the following code :

```
if (Open[1] < Close[1])
{
     double wanted_level = High[1];
}
if (Close[1] > iHigh(NULL, 0, iHighest(NULL, 0, MODE_HIGH, 50, 2))) {
     openSellTrade(); 
}
```

But it fail, because new Close[1] value conflict with old Close[1], how to solve it?

Comment: I do not know whether there is any sense in the example of the task you provided, but if we think of "N bullish candles in a row" or sth similar, that could make sense. You can store such cases in `CArrayObj` and recheck them all every new bar to get a signal you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand clearly, please. Are you trying to put a sell-limit order to the highest price of the last 50 bars range, after a simple green bar?

Comment: no. When highest bar appear, then save the highest price into a variable. Then wait for next bar close above it. Maybe the next bar fail to close above it, so wait for another next bar, and another next bar fail to close above it, so wait for another next new bar, and if the next new bar success close above it, then open a sell trade.